# Minimizing Window in shortcut -Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Is there a way to assign a shortcut for Minimizing a window the Alt-Space-n sequence in just one keyboardshortcut?

Comment: Just get a program that makes key-board shortcuts for you. My favorite is called Quic-Keys. Cost: $3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script for [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) defines CTRL+M to minimize the current window:

```
^m::WinMinimize,A
```

You can define any hotkey you want by replacing the "^m". The codes to use are listed [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro).

Answer (score 0):

This [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script will set up 'Win + Space' to minimise the current window:

> #space::Send !{space}n

Comment: ...though Snark's 'WinMinimize' looks more elegent.